# EventToCommand missing in blend vs2015

Tags: mvvm-light

i'm using mvvmlight v5.2.0 template in visual studio 2015, update 2.  when i design my window UWP project build 10586 in blend, the assets folder is missing EventToCommand behavior.

all i see are the 10 available behaviors added by the new open source Behaviors project.  should i be using one of these as an analogue to EventToCommand, e.g., EventTriggerBehavior?

missing a using statement, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use the `InvokeCommandAction` which does the same thing

eg Button Click to Command

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton">
  <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
                <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding YourCommandHere}"/>
            </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Button>
```

Make sure you have the following namespaces at the top of your xaml page

```
xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity" 
xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
```

Hope that helps

Comment: thanks- that did the trick.  mvvmlight author also states to use this blend behaviour in lieu of his own implementation.